# Receving 120 and 220 volt readings when testing a home outlet

Tags: electrical, grounding, grounding-and-bonding

I recently redid a room in my house (older home built in the 60's i believe). I decided to replace the outlets as well as they where loose and wouldn't hold plugs very well. When i pulled a few of the old outlets i found what i looked up to be called "bootleg grounds" on two of the three i replaced. I installed the new plugs without the jumper as they appear to be in conduit boxes and i read the jumper was a really bad idea. I looked up how to test these outlets to be sure the ground is there. (i have a nice fluke multi-meter) When i tested between the two slots i get 120v as expected, now hears where it gets weird and you have to forgive me as im a novice with electricity. when i tested from one slot to the ground hole i also got 120v which i believe is the hot to the ground so that should be expect as well, but when i switch to the other slot to the ground hole i get 220v, which i believe is a big problem, what i want to know is what could be the cause of this so i can try to start hunting this down. Could it be other outlets down the circuit with bootleg grounds causing the voltage to double essentially acting like a 220 circuit? I'm going to start looking for other outlets with the bootleg grounds but i wanted to get more info on this at the same time. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I ran around and tested a few more outlets some I'm getting 330 volts at and other 500+ volts..

Comment: Something is *very* not right here -- does this occur for all outlets in the house, or just some?

Comment: it appears to be all of them, i just went and tested the kitchen and the bathroom, im getting 330 in the bathroom and 500 something in the kitchen...

Comment: *blinks* What sort of meter are you using for this? I suspect that something is hideously awry with it...

Comment: Are you sure you're really seeing 500 v, and not 500 millivolts?  Those meters can automatically switch scales.

Comment: Voltage over 250V should not be present anywhere in a home.  On a 3-prong outlet, one slot is slightly taller, that is neutral and should be quite close to ground, certainly within 3 volts and commonly within 1 volt.

Comment: thats totally possible too i believe i'm testing right from what i read online but that could be wrong, its a Fluke 179 true rms multi-meter, im using the red and black leads to the red V and COM connections. Is there a certain way to test the outlet? I read i should see 120v from hot to ground and Zero from neutral to ground.

Comment: Are you sure you're really seeing 500 v, and not 500 millivolts? Those meters can automatically switch scales. – Mark 6 mins ago
OMG this was it... im kicking myself now. Everything looks ok im getting 120 between slots, 120 from one to ground and like 2 volts from other slot to ground.. THANK YOU GUYS SO MUCH, i was running around thinking my house was going to explode!

Comment: Can you define what you believe a boot leg ground is. I started to write that it sounds like you have a multi wire branch circuit 2 Hot's 1 ground and 1 neutral going back to 2 breakers if incorrectly wired there can be 240 V RMS. This is the maximum voltage available in 99% of all homes in the U.S. If your meter was reading peak to peak values it could be as high as ~400v so there is something wrong with your meter. All the fluke meters I have measure RMS. Industrial 3 phase 480v systems phase to ground will only measure 277 so the 330 & 500v readings just cannot be correct.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you're really seeing 500 v, and not 500 millivolts? Those meters can automatically switch scales. – Mark 6 mins ago OMG this was it... im kicking myself now. Everything looks ok im getting 120 between slots, 120 from one to ground and like 2 volts from other slot to ground.. THANK YOU GUYS SO MUCH, i was running around thinking my house was going to explode!

Comment: Glad it helped!